# How to download files from production to development machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have debugging an issue with regard to my assets, and want to download the contents of the public/assets library on Heroku to a folder on my development machine. What would be the best way to do this?

I can do

```
heroku run bash
```

which starts a heroku bash shell on my local development machine. Using this, I can list files on heroku instance of the app. But how do I copy these files down to the file system of my local development machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the assets like the logo should be part of your git repo. if you dont have and you want to download the repo from heroku you can do

```
heroku git:clone -a myapp
```

you can also pull the repo from heroku like

```
git pull heroku master
```

and you can alose rebase from heroku  like

```
git pull --rebase heroku master
```

I hope that this helps :)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app

Comment: I have accepted and upvoted this as it answers my question. It however, does not solve my problem.  I want to download the assets from a particular release.  If I roll back to that release and do a ```git pull heroku master``` it says that it is up to date. As far as I can see, the git repository on heroku is a replica of the one on my local machine, and so does not include assets which are added by precompiling on heroku.  Any idea how to get at these?

Comment: could those assets be in the .gitignore ?

Comment: No, they are not in .giitignore. The problem is that if the precompile happens on heroku, then they are not committed.

Answer (score 0):

heroku is not really good at holding assets specially if they are uploaded by the users.

I would recommend uploading them using [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and then you can just point your end point to be the same as prod.

my setup is:

My Gemfile

```
#Gemfile 
gem 'fog', "~> 1.3.1"
gem 'carrierwave'
```

initializers

```
#config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['CARRIER_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['CARRIER_WAVE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['CARRIER_WAVE_BUCKET']
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000' }
end
```

uploaders

## app/uploaders/file_uploader.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

I know that this was not exactly your question but I hope that it helps

:)

Comment: Sorry, this does not help. Heroku as a matter of course does store image assets etc used by ruby on rails applications, for instance the logo. This is the sort of  asset I want to download.